# How to make a table more cells in a cell

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I'm making a hardware add-on on my site and I'm making a table there. In that table I need to do that by dividing into 4 main cells and in each another 3 subspecies and so on. I want to have an option to choose in those cells and therefore I don't know how to do it with it. I'll give you a sample of how I want it as a picture. I will also attach the code of what I have so far below. Thanks in advance for your help.

```html
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>Monitor</td>
      <td>
         <select id="monitorSelect">
            <option>-----</option>
            <option>zobrazuje grafický výstup</option>
            <option>může fungovat k ovládání počítače</option>
            <option>reprodukuje zvuk</option>
            <option>může nahrávat zvuk</option>
            <option>nahrává video</option>
            <option>zobrazuje grafický výstup</option>
         </select>
         <select id="monitor2Select">
            <option>-----</option>
            <option>zobrazuje grafický výstup</option>
            <option>může fungovat k ovládání počítače</option>
            <option>reprodukuje zvuk</option>
            <option>může nahrávat zvuk</option>
            <option>nahrává video</option>
            <option>zobrazuje grafický výstup</option>
         </select>
         <select id="monitor3Select">
            <option>-----</option>
            <option>zobrazuje grafický výstup</option>
            <option>může fungovat k ovládání počítače</option>
            <option>reprodukuje zvuk</option>
            <option>může nahrávat zvuk</option>
            <option>nahrává video</option>
            <option>zobrazuje grafický výstup</option>
         </select>
      </td>
      <td>
         <select id="monitor4Select">
            <option>-----</option>
            <option>dotykovost</option>
            <option>velikost (palce)</option>
            <option>konektor</option>
            <option>způsob připojení</option>
            <option>integrovaný mikrofon</option>
            <option>rozlišení (px)</option>
            <option>rychlost (str./min)</option>
            <option>technologie tisku</option>
            <option>černobílá/barevná</option>
         </select>
         <select id="monitor5Select">
            <option>-----</option>
            <option>dotykovost</option>
            <option>velikost (palce)</option>
            <option>konektor</option>
            <option>způsob připojení</option>
            <option>integrovaný mikrofon</option>
            <option>rozlišení (px)</option>
            <option>rychlost (str./min)</option>
            <option>technologie tisku</option>
            <option>černobílá/barevná</option>
         </select>
         <select id="monitor6Select">
            <option>-----</option>
            <option>dotykovost</option>
            <option>velikost (palce)</option>
            <option>konektor</option>
            <option>způsob připojení</option>
            <option>integrovaný mikrofon</option>
            <option>rozlišení (px)</option>
            <option>rychlost (str./min)</option>
            <option>technologie tisku</option>
            <option>černobílá/barevná</option>
         </select>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Sluchátka</td>
      <td>
         <select id="sluchatkaSelect">
            <option>-----</option>
            <option>zobrazuje grafický výstup</option>
            <option>může fungovat k ovládání počítače</option>
            <option>reprodukuje zvuk</option>
            <option>může nahrávat zvuk</option>
            <option>nahrává video</option>
            <option>zobrazuje grafický výstup</option>
         </select>
         <select id="sluchatka2Select">
            <option>-----</option>
            <option>zobrazuje grafický výstup</option>
            <option>může fungovat k ovládání počítače</option>
            <option>reprodukuje zvuk</option>
            <option>může nahrávat zvuk</option>
            <option>nahrává video</option>
            <option>zobrazuje grafický výstup</option>
         </select>
         <select id="sluchatka3Select">
            <option>-----</option>
            <option>zobrazuje grafický výstup</option>
            <option>může fungovat k ovládání počítače</option>
            <option>reprodukuje zvuk</option>
            <option>může nahrávat zvuk</option>
            <option>nahrává video</option>
            <option>zobrazuje grafický výstup</option>
         </select>
      </td>
      <td>
         <select id="sluchatka4Select">
            <option>-----</option>
            <option>dotykovost</option>
            <option>velikost (palce)</option>
            <option>konektor</option>
            <option>způsob připojení</option>
            <option>integrovaný mikrofon</option>
            <option>rozlišení (px)</option>
            <option>rychlost (str./min)</option>
            <option>technologie tisku</option>
            <option>černobílá/barevná</option>
         </select>
         <select id="sluchatka5Select">
            <option>-----</option>
            <option>dotykovost</option>
            <option>velikost (palce)</option>
            <option>konektor</option>
            <option>způsob připojení</option>
            <option>integrovaný mikrofon</option>
            <option>rozlišení (px)</option>
            <option>rychlost (str./min)</option>
            <option>technologie tisku</option>
            <option>černobílá/barevná</option>
         </select>
         <select id="sluchatka6Select">
            <option>-----</option>
            <option>dotykovost</option>
            <option>velikost (palce)</option>
            <option>konektor</option>
            <option>způsob připojení</option>
            <option>integrovaný mikrofon</option>
            <option>rozlišení (px)</option>
            <option>rychlost (str./min)</option>
            <option>technologie tisku</option>
            <option>černobílá/barevná</option>
         </select>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Kamera</td>
      <td>
         <select id="kameraSelect">
            <option>-----</option>
            <option>zobrazuje grafický výstup</option>
            <option>může fungovat k ovládání počítače</option>
            <option>reprodukuje zvuk</option>
            <option>může nahrávat zvuk</option>
            <option>nahrává video</option>
            <option>zobrazuje grafický výstup</option>
         </select>
         <select id="kamera2Select">
            <option>-----</option>
            <option>zobrazuje grafický výstup</option>
            <option>může fungovat k ovládání počítače</option>
            <option>reprodukuje zvuk</option>
            <option>může nahrávat zvuk</option>
            <option>nahrává video</option>
            <option>zobrazuje grafický výstup</option>
         </select>
         <select id="kamera3Select">
            <option>-----</option>
            <option>zobrazuje grafický výstup</option>
            <option>může fungovat k ovládání počítače</option>
            <option>reprodukuje zvuk</option>
            <option>může nahrávat zvuk</option>
            <option>nahrává video</option>
            <option>zobrazuje grafický výstup</option>
         </select>
      </td>
      <td>
         <select id="kamera4Select">
            <option>-----</option>
            <option>dotykovost</option>
            <option>velikost (palce)</option>
            <option>konektor</option>
            <option>způsob připojení</option>
            <option>integrovaný mikrofon</option>
            <option>rozlišení (px)</option>
            <option>rychlost (str./min)</option>
            <option>technologie tisku</option>
            <option>černobílá/barevná</option>
         </select>
         <select id="kamera5Select">
            <option>-----</option>
            <option>dotykovost</option>
            <option>velikost (palce)</option>
            <option>konektor</option>
            <option>způsob připojení</option>
            <option>integrovaný mikrofon</option>
            <option>rozlišení (px)</option>
            <option>rychlost (str./min)</option>
            <option>technologie tisku</option>
            <option>černobílá/barevná</option>
         </select>
         <select id="kamera6Select">
            <option>-----</option>
            <option>dotykovost</option>
            <option>velikost (palce)</option>
            <option>konektor</option>
            <option>způsob připojení</option>
            <option>integrovaný mikrofon</option>
            <option>rozlišení (px)</option>
            <option>rychlost (str./min)</option>
            <option>technologie tisku</option>
            <option>černobílá/barevná</option>
         </select>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Tiskárna</td>
      <td>
         <select id="tiskárnaSelect">
            <option>-----</option>
            <option>zobrazuje grafický výstup</option>
            <option>může fungovat k ovládání počítače</option>
            <option>reprodukuje zvuk</option>
            <option>může nahrávat zvuk</option>
            <option>nahrává video</option>
            <option>zobrazuje grafický výstup</option>
         </select>
         <select id="tiskárna2Select">
            <option>-----</option>
            <option>zobrazuje grafický výstup</option>
            <option>může fungovat k ovládání počítače</option>
            <option>reprodukuje zvuk</option>
            <option>může nahrávat zvuk</option>
            <option>nahrává video</option>
            <option>zobrazuje grafický výstup</option>
         </select>
         <select id="tiskárna3Select">
            <option>-----</option>
            <option>zobrazuje grafický výstup</option>
            <option>může fungovat k ovládání počítače</option>
            <option>reprodukuje zvuk</option>
            <option>může nahrávat zvuk</option>
            <option>nahrává video</option>
            <option>zobrazuje grafický výstup</option>
         </select>
      </th>
      <th>
         <select id="tiskárna4Select">
            <option>-----</option>
            <option>dotykovost</option>
            <option>velikost (palce)</option>
            <option>konektor</option>
            <option>způsob připojení</option>
            <option>integrovaný mikrofon</option>
            <option>rozlišení (px)</option>
            <option>rychlost (str./min)</option>
            <option>technologie tisku</option>
            <option>černobílá/barevná</option>
         </select>
         <select id="tiskárna5Select">
            <option>-----</option>
            <option>dotykovost</option>
            <option>velikost (palce)</option>
            <option>konektor</option>
            <option>způsob připojení</option>
            <option>integrovaný mikrofon</option>
            <option>rozlišení (px)</option>
            <option>rychlost (str./min)</option>
            <option>technologie tisku</option>
            <option>černobílá/barevná</option>
         </select>
         <select id="tiskárna6Select">
            <option>-----</option>
            <option>dotykovost</option>
            <option>velikost (palce)</option>
            <option>konektor</option>
            <option>způsob připojení</option>
            <option>integrovaný mikrofon</option>
            <option>rozlišení (px)</option>
            <option>rychlost (str./min)</option>
            <option>technologie tisku</option>
            <option>černobílá/barevná</option>
         </select>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**Sample image of how I want it to look:**

[image]

Comment: If you're convinced that tables are appropriate for your use case, you can nest a 3-row table inside each cell in the middle and right columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a new row `(tr)` for each line of the table that you want to divide.

After that, you assign the attribute `"rowspan"` at the first column matching the number of the rows that it covers (3 in your case).

Here is the related documentation about the `"rowspan"` attribute on W3Schools website: [**click here!**](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_rowspan.asp)

Anyway, here you are the first 3 rows of the table you need, just to better understand how this system works:

```html
<table border="1">
   <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">Monitor</td>
      <td>
         <select id="monitorSelect">
            <option>-----</option>
            <option>zobrazuje grafický výstup</option>
            <option>může fungovat k ovládání počítače</option>
            <option>reprodukuje zvuk</option>
            <option>může nahrávat zvuk</option>
            <option>nahrává video</option>
            <option>zobrazuje grafický výstup</option>
         </select>
      </td>
      <td>
         <select id="monitor4Select">
            <option>-----</option>
            <option>dotykovost</option>
            <option>velikost (palce)</option>
            <option>konektor</option>
            <option>způsob připojení</option>
            <option>integrovaný mikrofon</option>
            <option>rozlišení (px)</option>
            <option>rychlost (str./min)</option>
            <option>technologie tisku</option>
            <option>černobílá/barevná</option>
         </select>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <select id="monitor2Select">
            <option>-----</option>
            <option>zobrazuje grafický výstup</option>
            <option>může fungovat k ovládání počítače</option>
            <option>reprodukuje zvuk</option>
            <option>může nahrávat zvuk</option>
            <option>nahrává video</option>
            <option>zobrazuje grafický výstup</option>
         </select>
      </td>
      <td>
         <select id="monitor5Select">
            <option>-----</option>
            <option>dotykovost</option>
            <option>velikost (palce)</option>
            <option>konektor</option>
            <option>způsob připojení</option>
            <option>integrovaný mikrofon</option>
            <option>rozlišení (px)</option>
            <option>rychlost (str./min)</option>
            <option>technologie tisku</option>
            <option>černobílá/barevná</option>
         </select>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <select id="monitor3Select">
            <option>-----</option>
            <option>zobrazuje grafický výstup</option>
            <option>může fungovat k ovládání počítače</option>
            <option>reprodukuje zvuk</option>
            <option>může nahrávat zvuk</option>
            <option>nahrává video</option>
            <option>zobrazuje grafický výstup</option>
         </select>
      </td>
      <td>
         <select id="monitor6Select">
            <option>-----</option>
            <option>dotykovost</option>
            <option>velikost (palce)</option>
            <option>konektor</option>
            <option>způsob připojení</option>
            <option>integrovaný mikrofon</option>
            <option>rozlišení (px)</option>
            <option>rychlost (str./min)</option>
            <option>technologie tisku</option>
            <option>černobílá/barevná</option>
         </select>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <!-- and so on in other rows -->
</table>
```

*P.S. if you need to show the border on your table, just set the attribute `"border"` with value `"1"` on your table main tag!*

Andrea

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed.